# Change dynamically the content of a <select> according to a variable value

Tags: reactjs

I have 2 `select` Elements on a page,
The first has only 2 options : movies and TV shows, and it's set on movies by default,
According to the option selected, the second select show the genres of the first select chosen,

Example :

If the 1st select value chosen is movies, then the second select contains all movies genres (https://api.themoviedb.org/3/genre/tv/list?api_key=381e8c936f62f2ab614e9f29cad6630f&language=en)

And, if the 1st select value chosen is TV shows, then the second select contains all TV show genres
(https://api.themoviedb.org/3/genre/movie/list?api_key=381e8c936f62f2ab614e9f29cad6630f&language=en),

I thought that what I did was ok, but when I change the first select value, the second select doesn't change its options,

```
function handleMediaTypeChange(e) {
    setMediaType(e.target.value);
    forceUpdate();
}

function handleGenreChange(e) {
    setNameGenreChosen(
      $(".selected:eq(1)")
        .children("span")
        .text()
    );
    setIdGenreChosen(
      mediaType === "movie"
        ? moviesGenres.find(genre => genre.name === e.target.value).id
        : tvGenres.find(genre => genre.name === e.target.value).id
    );
    forceUpdate();
  }

<div className="row">
          <div className="input-field col s12 m6">
            <p>Choose your type of fiction</p>
            <select style={{ zIndex: "999" }} onChange={handleMediaTypeChange}>
              <option value="" disabled defaultValue>
                Choose your type of fiction
              </option>
              <option value="movie">Films</option>
              <option value="tv">TV shows</option>
            </select>
          </div>

          <div className="input-field col s12 m6">
            <p>Choose a category</p>
            {mediaType === "movie" ? (
              <select onChange={handleGenreChange}>
                <option value="" disabled defaultValue>
                  Select a category
                </option>
                {moviesGenres &&
                  moviesGenres.map(genre => (
                    <option value={genre.name} key={genre.id} id={genre.id}>
                      {genre.name}
                    </option>
                  ))}
              </select>
            ) : (
              <select onChange={handleGenreChange}>
                <option value="" disabled defaultValue>
                  Choisissez un genre
                </option>
                {tvGenres &&
                  tvGenres.map(genre => (
                    <option value={genre.name} key={genre.id} id={genre.id}>
                      {genre.name}
                    </option>
                  ))}
              </select>
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
```

**What I want to do : according to mediaType value, I change the select options**

The code is very dense, I had to cut some parts, but if you want I can show you the whole code.

You can test it on: https://ofilms.herokuapp.com/bibliotheque

Comment: I assume this is a functional component (not a class component)? In addition, what does `forceUpdate` do?

Comment: yes functional components with hooks, and forceupdate is a package that refresh the component after a the execution of a function https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-force-update

Comment: Hmm.. I checked the network request, and it seems like you aren't making the request to fetch the genres whenever you select a new option from the select. Maybe you can show me the code whereby you make the request?

Comment: yes, the issue is that I don't know how to change select options when the mediaType (movies or TV shows) changed

Comment: What are the methods that update the `moviesGenres` and `tvGenres` state?

Comment: I don't understand the use of a "forceUpdate" function, if you've used hooks correctly then react should re-render upon updated values.

Comment: @wentjun moviesGenres and tvGenres don't get updated, they only change when they get loaded at the component mounts the first time, it's a function loadMoviesGenres() and loadTvGenres() in a useEffect done 1 time

Comment: Ahh, I see.. Ok I get it now.

Comment: their default value is false, and then it's equal to the json links I put you in the description of my issue